# Load the excel file which i open using dialog box in wpf into datagrid when i click open

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

```
private void btndilog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dilog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dilog.FileName = "Excel files";
            dilog.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
            dilog.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";

            ///show open file dialog box 
            bool? result = dilog.ShowDialog();
            ///process open file dialog box results
            if(result==true)
            {
                string filename = dilog.FileName;
            }
        }
```

**I wrote this code to load a excel file using dialog box now i want when ever i click on the open button all the data of that excel file to get loaded into my datagrid ,since am new to c# and wpf am getting trouble doing that can anyone please help me out

[Datagrid where i want to display the details of excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiJbC.png)

[Excel file that i want to load to my data grid my i click on open button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9JaS.png)

Comment: To achieve your task, you need to use a library that is able to process excel files. For example, you could take a look at VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and use this piece of code to first  read your file into datatable and then to bind the datatable with the datagrid**

```
//using a click event 
       private void MnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
    
    //using dialog box to open the excel file and giving the extension as .xlsx to open the excel files
                OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
                openfile.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
                openfile.Filter = "(.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
    
                ///show open file dialog box 
                bool? result = openfile.ShowDialog();
                ///process open file dialog box results
                if (result == true)
                {
//copying the path of the excel file to a textbox named txtFilePath
                    txtFilePath.Text = openfile.FileName;
    //Add reference then select Microsoft .Office.Interop.Excel
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    //Static File From Base Path...........
                    //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "TestExcel.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
                    //Dynamic File Using Uploader...........
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(txtFilePath.Text.ToString(), 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); ;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;
    //reading the excel file in the datatable
                    string strCellData = "";
                    double douCellData;
                    int rowCnt = 0;
                    int colCnt = 0;
    
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    for (colCnt = 1; colCnt <= excelRange.Columns.Count; colCnt++)
                    {
                        string strColumn = "";
                        strColumn = (string)(excelRange.Cells[1, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                        dt.Columns.Add(strColumn, typeof(string));
                    }
    
                    for (rowCnt = 2; rowCnt <= excelRange.Rows.Count; rowCnt++)
                    {
                        string strData = "";
                        for (colCnt = 1; colCnt <= excelRange.Columns.Count; colCnt++)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                strCellData = (string)(excelRange.Cells[rowCnt, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                                strData += strCellData + "|";
                            }
                            catch (Exception Ex)
                            {
                                douCellData = (excelRange.Cells[rowCnt, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                                strData += douCellData.ToString() + "|";
                            }
                        }
                        strData = strData.Remove(strData.Length - 1, 1);
                        dt.Rows.Add(strData.Split('|'));
                    }
    
                    dtGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    
                    excelBook.Close(true, null, null);
                    excelApp.Quit();
    
                }
    
    
            }
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.